# BC42104 error code how can I fix this error?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

> Warning BC42104: Variable 'pass' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim uname As String = ""
    Dim pword As String
    Dim username As String = ""
    Dim pass As String
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill the info")
    Else
        uname = TextBox1.Text
        pword = TextBox2.Text
        Dim query As String = "Select Password From Register where Username= '" & uname & "';"
        Dim dbsource As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gui\Documents\Database4.accdb"
        Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Try
            pass = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Username does not exit")
        End Try
        If (pword = pass) Then
            MsgBox("Login success")
            Reg.Show()
            If Reg.Visible Then
                Me.Hide()
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox("login Failed")
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, use your favourite search engine and type the error number. You will find thousands links that explain the problem. A lot of them are questions and answers on this same site.

Comment: i already did but most of them are too complicated to understand i am new with programming and i want to learn more. but i keep on seeing this error.

Comment: So let's try to read again the error message: _the variable 'inst' is used before it has been assigned a value_ The variable _inst_ is nowhere in your code above. So the error message is not relative to this snippet. Better look for your code where you _use_ this variable called _inst_ and add that code here.

Comment: im so sorry the variable was 'pass' not 'inst' miss-looked the question.

Comment: Allright, now suppose your line _pass = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString_ triggers an exception. The code will continue to the catch block **without** setting a value in the variable _pass_. After the code exits from the catch block you compare the value of _pass_ with _pword_. Do you see the problem now? The compiler tries to tell you about this problem and don't allow your code to be compiled. You fix it just setting the _pass_ variable to a default value as you are already doing with _uname_

Comment: thanks steve i'll try to work it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the error is saying, you are not initializing the variable **pass** and under some condition, you may end up with using it.

To be exact, if the control lands in the '**catch**' block, the variable '**pass**' will not have any values, which means it is possible that `If (pword = pass)` statement is reached without this variable having any values.

To fix the error, just assign a null value or empty string to the variable at the point of initialization. For example use this statement:

```
Dim pass As String = "";
```